# RequestParser.parse_args() not recognizing arguments

Tags: python, api, rest, put, flask-restful

I'm creating a REST API with flask_restful and want to parse the arguments coming from a PUT request. Below is the relevant code:

```
user_put_args = reqparse.RequestParser()
user_put_args.add_argument("user_id", type="str", help="user_id is needed for this user")
user_put_args.add_argument("spotify_username", type="str", help="Spotify username for the corresponding user_id")
user_put_args.add_argument("apple_music_username", type="str", help="Apple Music username for the corresponding user_id")
```

PUT function declaration:

```
def put(self, user_id):
   args = user_put_args.parse_args()
   rest of code ...
```

and here's the put request:

```
req4 = requests.put(HEROKU_BASE + "/users/" + "test1", {"spotify_username": "test_1", "apple_music_username":"something"})
print(req4.json())
```

The response I'm getting from the put call is:

```
{'message': {'spotify_username': 'Spotify username for the corresponding user_id'}}
```

meaning it's getting hung up on the request parse.

Any ideas on how to fix this? I'm following a guide that led me to this and my code is almost exactly the same. Thanks!

Comment: Help message shows instead of default error message, you can try removing it and see what exactly error is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write `type="str"`, reqparser tries to call the argument of `type` on your data and it is cannot be done with string
You shouldn't use quotes there, it will just be:
`user_put_args.add_argument("spotify_username", type=str, help="Spotify username for the corresponding user_id")`